# When would you use `presume` in an Isar proof?

Tags: isabelle, isar

Isar has, besides `assume`, also the command `presume` to introduce facts in an Isar proof block. From what I can see and read in the docs, it does not require the assumption (presumption?) to be explicitly listed in the goal, and seems to add a case to show that the presumed statement follows from the other goals.

So the question is: When would I use `presume` instead of `assume`, and what nice tricks can I do with `presume`?

Comment: Note that even `assume` does not require the assumption to be explicit in the goal premises.  What counts is that the exported rule from the subproof can be resolved with some goal in the manner that is explained in the isar-ref manual section 2.1.2 Reasoning with rules (refinement).  These principles are more general than most people expect, e.g. the goal might be schematic and the application than invents suitable premises via unification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`presume` does not make the Isar language more expressive, because you can restructure every proof with `presume` into one with `assume` only. Nevertheless, there are at least two (more or less common) use cases:

First, `presume` sometimes leads to more natural proofs, because you can use `presume` like a cut.

For example, suppose that you your proof state has two goals `A ==> C` and `B ==> C`, and you can proof that some `E` follows from `A` and from `B` given the facts in the current context and `E` and the facts in the current context imply `C`. With `presume`, you can structure the proof as follows:

```
   presume E
   show C <proof using E and facts>
   thus C .
 next
   assume A
   thus E <proof using A and facts>
   thus E .
 next
   assume B
   thus E <proof using A and facts>
   thus E .
```

In `assume` style, this looks as follows:

```
   assume A
   hence E <proof using A and facts>
   show C <proof using E and facts>
 next
   assume B
   hence E <proof using B and facts>
   show C <proof using E and facts>
```

With `presume`, the structure of the proof is more explicit: Apparently, we only need `E` to show the results and this might be the interesting part of the proof. Moreover, in `assume` style, we have to do the proof that `E` implies `C` twice. Of course, this can always be factored out into a lemma, but if the proof needs a lot of facts from the context, that can become ugly.

Second, you can use `presume` while you write a proof to locate typing errors in `assume`s and `show`s. Suppose you have

```
 fix x
 assume A and B and C and D and E
 show F
```

but Isabelle tells you that the `show` will not solve any goal, i.e., you probably have some typo in the assumptions or the goal statement. Now, turn `assume` into `presume`. If `show` still fails, then the mistake is somewhere in the goal statement. Otherwise, it is probably somewhere in the assumptions. Close the `show` proof with `sorry` and try to discharge the assumptions with `apply_end(assumption)+`. It will stop at the assumption that it cannot unify. Probably, this is the one that is wrong.

Comment: I knew I can expect a good and generally useful answer from you! :-)

Comment: Even with assume, you can extract the proof `E ==> C` by doing: `{ assume E have C}` first and the nesting the proofs of `A ==> C and `B ==> C` into proof blocks: `{ assume A show E` } `{ assume B show E}`. You still might find the presume style nicer.